# Not Found route for multiple Switches in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my main Routes component, I handle three different routes with their corresponding Switches: `PublicRoutes, PrivateRoutes and AuthRoutes`.

**Router.tsx**

```
export default function Routes(): JSX.Element {
  const [user] = useUser();
  return (
    <Switch>
      {/* If user is logged in, show PrivateRoutes, else the AuthRoutes */}
      <Route>
        <PublicRoutes />
        {user.user ? <PrivateRoutes /> : <AuthRoutes />}
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

All three components share almost the same body, a Switch with its content routes, here is an example of AuthRoutes.

**AuthRoutes.tsx**

```
export default function AuthRoutes(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Switch>
      {/* Login Pages */}
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/oauth-callback" component={Authentication} />

      {/* Error route when no other paths are found */}
      <Route
        component={() => (
          <ErrorPage
            errorCode={ERROR_403_ROUTE.errorCode}
            errorMessage={ERROR_403_ROUTE.errorMessage}
          />
        )}
      />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

The issue here is when I navigate through a `PublicRoutes` route. As you can see, in the `AuthRoutes` I have a "Not Found" component to render if the path does not match with the routes, the problem is that on the `PublicRoutes` component, the "Not Found" is also rendering below the `PublicRoutes` route. Is there a way to create a "Not Found" component for all of the 3 Switches recognizing all of their paths?

Comment: I can see you rendering public routes as well as private routes either auth routes based on the user logged in. you not checking first the user is logged in or not, directly rendering one.

Comment: Hey @GolamrabbiAzad, even if I remove that validation and just render `PublicRoutes` and `PrivateRoutes` the issue persists.